# Turn on a little engine with the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to turn on a little engine with the iphone
I mean, using the 30-pin cable and connecting some cables to the engine.
Which is the code I have to write to do that?
And the most important, is that possible or is just a dream?

Comment: If that's as far as you could get -- asking a vague question here -- then the answer is probably "no, you can't do it".  If you could open the SDK documentation, read the iPhone API's and ask a specific question about a specific API that makes use of the USB interface the phone has, then the answer might change.

Comment: Writing a *check* would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you want the [External Accessory Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference.pdf)?

> The External Accessory framework provides support for communicating with external hardware connected to an iPhone OS–based device through the 30-pin dock connector or wirelessly using Bluetooth.

Also see Apple's [landing page for accessory developers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/accessories/).

Comment: Note that you will need to become an approved member of the Made for iPod program to directly control your accessory via this framework, which will take a lot more time and money than he'd be willing to spend for a hobby project.  However, it sounds like some general-purpose accessories may be on the way that might let him control his engine via their analog or digital outputs.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you have to convince Apple to let you do it.  The connector itself is a proprietary design, and Apple's approval is required before Molex will sell it to you.  Also, they're not really set up for hobbyists or experimenters; they want to deal with people making hardware add-ons to sell to the general public.